# How to uniquely identify a azure solution?

Tags: azure

Is there any way to detect an azure solution uniquely?
I want to develop a library that is licensed per solution.
The only way to enforce this without having a licensing server is to have a unique identity of the solution. Is any GUID of such sort available?

Something like RoleEnvironment.DeploymentID.

When does DeploymentID change?

According to smarx on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/94ccd4e0-7c23-4a90-83b7-33a4d95a3deb use of DeploymentID does NOT help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeploymentID changes when people deploy (to staging or production).  It doesn't change when staging and production are swapped, and it doesn't change during an in-place upgrade.

Comment: That would mean DeploymentID can not be used to identify a solution uniquely and its not feasible to use it for enforcing license of 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

(A year after the question was asked, but here's another idea...)

Lock down based on the public Azure cloudapp.net subdomain the app is using. This should work fine even if the customer has a custom domain, as their cloudapp.net subdomain would still resolve. For example. the Boston Azure User Group site is located at http://www.bostonazure.org (custom domain), but still can be reached via http://bostonazure.cloudapp.net.

Downsides: You still need to handle generated test addresses generated by Azure - but perhaps you allow these since they are impractical to expose to customers. Also, customers would be constrained to always deploy to the same cloudapp.net subdomain.

Comment: How would the API know which domain is using it?

Comment: @Hasan: Please provide clarification: Are you trying to make your API work 100% within the bounds of a deployed Azure app - in other words, you do not provide any separately hosted service that the application calls? For example, if you provide (just to pick an example) a PDF generator library that your customers can deploy, you seek a way to lock down that library to only services for which it is licensed?

Comment: Yes there is no separate hosted instance.

Comment: @Hasan - Awkward, but couple of ways. 1. Given Subscription ID you can use Service Management API to look up the corresponding public URL. (See Get Deployment API: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx) There is complexity here with certificate setup to call Service Management API. The current Deployment ID is returned and can be compared to what's in RoleEnvironment. 2. Expose an endpoint ("MyServiceValidator") and have the service call back into itself via mysite.cloudapp.net which will allow it to compare its actual current domain (from request) with expected. HTH. -Bill